# Failed to install Adobe Flash Catalyst CS5.5 - 1 Fatal Error

Tags: flash

The first time I installed the program was right after the Adobe Download Manager finished downloading it. It gave me 1 fatal error and 1 error. Then I went into the download folder and launched the set-up.exe as admin. Now it gives me only 1 Fatal Error. The details are as follows:

```
Exit Code: 7
-------------------------------------- Summary --------------------------------------

 - 1 fatal error(s), 0 error(s), 0 warning(s)

FATAL: Payload '{6B485102-4593-43F6-BA45-F14D690B0C64} Suite Shared Configuration CS5 5.0.44.0' information not found in Media_db.

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Btw, I'm running Windows 7 SP1 32bit

Comment: Ok, I've figured it out now. Renamed the "Adobe" folder and successfully installed Flash Catalyst, although I also need to reinstall all the other Adobe programs that are already installed.

Comment: if you've solved your problem, please post an answer to your question